# how to make Nodejs call synchronous then I can use it easily?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    var login = req.body.login;
    var pass = req.body.pass;

    var ret = CheckUserValid(login, pass);

  res.send(ret);
})

function CheckUserValid(login, pass,callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE login = ? AND pass= ?";
    client.query(sql, [login, pass], function selectResutl(err, results, fields) {
         console.log(results);
        if (!err) return true;
        else
            throw err;
    });
}
```

first Function is about request and second is about making call to mysql. because it's async so it's not worked.
Can someone let me know how I can make it work synchronously like in C#.

Comment: If you're going to use NodeJS, you might as well learn to write asynchronous code. The `CheckUserValid` function accepts a callback, so why not use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of your `CheckUserValid` method already implies a `callback`.
You can use that to call something when your db-request is done, like this:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var login = req.body.login;
  var pass  = req.body.pass;

  // use a closure here for the callback of checkUserValid
  checkUserValid(login, pass, function(err, isValid) {
    // send the response when checkUserValid is done
    res.send(isValid)
  });
})

function checkUserValid(login, pass, callback) {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE login = ? AND pass= ?";
  client.query(sql, [login, pass], function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
    if (!err) {
      // there is no error, pass null for the error
      // and true for the result
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      // an error occurred in the db-query
      // pass it to the callback
      callback(err)
    }
  });
}
```

By convention you should pass the `err` as first argument, but in the end that's up to you.
However you can pass the original error up to your initial function and handle it there.

Answer (score 3):

You should a look at [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) module.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the functions that you want to call in order

e.g. you can make `res.send(ret);` as the callback of your `CheckUserValid`